# pointer trying to access beyond the heap area

Tags: c

Below is a program to understand the undefined behaviour.
I'm allocating ptr with 10 *4 = 40 bytes of memory and i'm trying to access , So it has to give me an seg fault when done *(ptr+0x100) which is exceeding the 40 bytes. What is observed from the code is , it gives me seg fault at *(ptr+0xc000). Does it that it gives seg fault when it goes beyond the size of the heap? Why does it didt give me an seg fault when ptr tried to access ptr+100 which is out of the boundary of 40 bytes allocated to it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

main()
{
        int * ptr = malloc(10 * sizeof(int) );

        *ptr = 0x100;
        printf(" Done 1\n");

        *(ptr+0x9) = 0x90;
        printf(" Done 2\n");

        *(ptr+0x100) = 0x400;
        printf(" Done 3\n");

        *(ptr + 0x1000) = 0x4000;
        printf(" Done 4\n");

        *(ptr + 0x4000) = 0x4000;
        printf(" Done 5\n");

        *(ptr + 0x8000) = 0x8000;
        printf(" Done 6\n");

        *(ptr + 0xc000) = 0xc000;
        printf(" Done 7\n");
}
```

Comment: *"trying to understand undefined behaviour and corruption..."* and then *"So it has to give me an seg fault when..."*. Not sure you understand what the word "undefined" means.  There is little to understand here; you're invoking UB, meaning your program is left in an undefined state.  Sure, you can test this and that to see what your particular compiler does, but that's it.  Besides, there's not a single question mark in your post.  There's no question here.  There are however thousands of questions identical in spirit to this one already on SO.

Comment: You'd already made an error before you got to `int * ptr`...

Comment: Other things aside (many people already told what undefined is) - you getting segfault when you accessing non-yours memory page. Page isn't something malloc given to you - even if it was mmap()ed (which surely not guaranteed - it could be allocated in other places), each page is usually 4kb, not 40b you requested.

Comment: "So it has to give me an seg fault" -- Where do people get this idea? This is the second recent post making such a baseless claim and I've seen it at SO before. The compiler does not generate code to check for out of bounds array access and then signal a segfault -- segfaults happen precisely because there *isn't* any out of bounds check, and so they depend on memory layout and other factors.

Comment: @JimBalter: My bet; they started with Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing into the heap beyond a valid malloc'ed location results in undefined behavior. It may or may not result in a seg fault. Depends on what is in the heap location and how it is used by the rest of the program.

Your program may not fail at all. But it does corrupt the heap so eventually, if you program was longer you would see problems. Hard to find problems.

Answer (score 1):

As you know, your program invokes **undefined** behaviour. **Undefined** doesn't mean "guaranteed to segfault under all circumstances"; **undefined** means "a conforming implementation of the C compiler can output a program which does anything".

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to *understand* undefined behaviour, the whole point of calling it undefined is to make it clear that *anything* can happen.

In fact, the most annoying aspect of UB is that it sometimes works. At least if it failed consistently, a whole class of bugs would never hit the field.

Trying to understand UB is like trying to understand cats (or some ex-girlfriends). You may *think* you've got it sorted but then they'll turn on you :-)

Rather than understand, you should simply avoid.

Comment: Cats exhibit UB?! This explains everything about the cats I had...

Comment: I, of course, being the rational type, am a dog person :-)

Comment: Same here. I took care of cats for a friend and was nearly driven crazy :)

Comment: Understanding UB is important for tracking down bugs. The whole point of calling it undefined is most certainly *not* to make it clear that anything can happen ... I was on X3J11 and that is the furthest thing from our intent. It's called undefined behavior simply because the standard does not define what a conforming implementation must do, and the reason for that is to avoid unnecessarily putting constraints on implementations (unnecessary from the peculiar perspective of the C culture; most programming language cultures don't view such constraints as unnecessary).